# Inserting a Variable into a String using Regex - Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm having trouble inserting an outside variable into a string using regular expressions.

I have a string which looks like:

```
    string = "7  -"
```

And I want to insert a integer as a string into the space between the "7" and the "-", and I've tried to use interpolation, like so:

```
    variable = "15"
    string = string.gsub(/(\S?\d+)(\s)(\s)(\D)/, '\1\2#{variable}\3\4')
```

(the \S? is to account for any " - " attached to a digit for whether it is positive or negative)

The output is a string looking like this:

```
    "7 \#{variable} -"
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
    "7 15 -"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quote. Single-quoted string does not interpolate.

```
string = "7  -"
variable = "15"
string = string.gsub(/(\S?\d+)(\s)(\s)(\D)/, "\\1\\2#{variable}\\3\\4")
string # => "7 15 -"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I'm just learning Ruby, and usually use double quotes. Is it best practice to use double quotes most times? Or just when dealing with regex?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elegant solution to your problem:

```
s = "7  -"
v = 15
string = s.gsub(/\d\s/, "#{s.delete("-").strip} #{v}")
#=> "7 15 -"
```

Comment: How would delete and strip work in this case? I'm having a tough time following along.

Comment: `s.delete("-").strip` is: `delete` is removing the hyphen and `strip` is removing the white space from the instance of `s` as is: `s = "7  -"` The space is returned to the string here: `...ip}_\s_#{v}"` Understand?